# Open jpg file in Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I cannot open jpg file from documents directory. File exist, not nil, but when I'm try to open it into UIImageView - nothing happens. Can anybody help me?

Sample code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:address];
UIImage *img =[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: filename];
[imgView setImage:img];
```

**UPDATE**
This code perfectly works with png-files.

Comment: Log the file path and verify that it actually exists.

Comment: Is `imgView` in the view hierarchy or hidden? Just guessing.

Comment: imgView - UIImageView in the view hierarchy

Comment: Make sure `filename` is reference to the jpg file and `imgView` isn't nil.

Comment: what is value of the `filename`? have you logged it yet?

Comment: logged:   /var/mobile/Applications/app/Documents/2014-01-09--10:25:03.jpg

Comment: and imgView isn't nil

Comment: @STBY, are you sure that is the exact path you logged? because it is not correct. the `URL` must look similar like this: `file:///var/mobile/Applications/4F615084-40B4-4306-B3F4-43ABC44497ED/Documents/2014-01-09--10:25:03.jpg`.

Comment: I change 4BECD52-C5D3-4D0B-BE0A-7DD77588D687 to "app"

Comment: @STBY, that is not the path you have logged, isn't it? your path is **THIS**: `var/mobile/Applications/4F615084-40B4-4306-B3F4-43ABC44497ED/Documents2014-01-09--10:25:03.jpg`, and if you spot the missing slash between folder and filename, you would be closer to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not to use `-[NSString stringByAppendingString:]` when you modify your file path. `-[NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent:]` instead.

   `NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:address];`
2. Debug and check your file name `(NSString *)address` and your file path `(NSString *)filename` whether they are correct.

Comment: I've tried use stringByAppendingPathComponent, but without any result. File path correct - I've test it few times

Comment: I just said `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` instead.

Comment: sorry. I've tried stringByAppendingPathComponent: too

Comment: why not debug to check:
1. your `address`
2. your `filename`
3. if your `img` is nil

Comment: I comment this already. Address right, filename right, img and imgView isn't nil

Comment: @STBY, your path is just **not** correct, please pay more attention to look it closer.

Comment: @holex, here is my log: 
 filename __NSCFString * @"/var/mobile/Applications/74BECD52-C5D3-4D0B-BE0A-7DD77588D687/Documents/2014-01-08--12:26:45.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the path is not correct. that is your incorrect path:

```
var/mobile/Applications/<ID>/Documents2014-01-09--10:25:03.jpg
```

and that would be the **correct** path:

```
var/mobile/Applications/<ID>/Documents/2014-01-09--10:25:03.jpg
```

(spot the missing slash between the folder and the file name);

---

try this one:

```
NSURL *_resourceURL = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"2014-01-09--10:25:03.jpg"];
UIImage *_image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[_resourceURL path]];
```

---

(it has been tested on *real* device only!)

Comment: are testing on real device? can you log the `_image` ivar to me, please? (`NSLog(@"%@", _image);`)

Comment: Of course. Here's log: <UIImage: 0x14db8d20>

Comment: so, that means it has been loaded well. your problem can be in the rest of your code; because the image file is loaded into the memory properly (you just presented the log about it) – otherwise the pointer would be `nil`.

Comment: My next action - [imgView setImage:_image] and nothing more

Comment: fact is the image is loaded... have you logged this yet: `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(imgView.frame));`?

Comment: Result: {{0, 134}, {320, 346}}

What does it mean?

Comment: that means the `UIImageView` is on the screen, however it does not provide information about whether there is another view which may overlap it. everything looks fine. the problem is somewhere else. you may need to provide more details because there is no problem with loading the image.

Comment: If I open this file right after saving in main view - it opens perfectly. If I try to open this file in other view - png files open, jpg files doesn't open.

Comment: @STBY, put your code into a github/bitbucket folder to take a deeper look on it.